# Same texture attached to different FBOs

Tags: opengl

This is probably a bizarre question but it's the first time I encounter this problem. I have an FBO-A which has a texture attachment. At some point in my pipeline I want to attach the texture from FBO-A to some temporary FBO-B to do a render pass. How does it impacts the original attachment if at all? Will that texture still remain attached to the FBO-A after attachment and  usage with FBO-B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will that texture still remain attached to the FBO-A after attachment and usage with FBO-B?

#### Yes.

**§ 9.2.2:**

> A single framebuffer-attachable image may be attached to multiple framebuffer
> objects, potentially avoiding some data copies, and possibly decreasing memory
> consumption.

Comment: Great!That's exactly what I wanted to be sure of.